How do I push my floatingActinButton when the keyboard appears - Flutter
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  floatingActionButton: floatingWidget(Get.height, Get.width),
  backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
  body: ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
    children: [
      HeaderLogoWidget(width: Get.width, height: Get.height),
      sectionWidget(Get.height, Get.width),
    ],
  ),
);

I need my Textfield to be focused when focus is pressed on it, and any bottombar at the bottom to be pushed up.
  Widget sectionWidget(double height, double width) {
return Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(height * 0.025),
  width: width * 0.85,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
        spreadRadius: 5,
        blurRadius: 7,
        offset: Offset(0, 3),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
  child: Form(
    key: controller.formKey,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Center(
            child: Image.asset("assets/logos/logofront.png",
                height: height * 0.10)),
        SizedBox(height: height * 0.02),
        buildTextField(FontAwesomeIcons.weebly, "text_field_web".tr, false,
            TextInputType.text, controller.web, "web"),
        buildTextField(FontAwesomeIcons.at, "text_field_usuario".tr, false,
            TextInputType.text, controller.email, "usuario"),
       InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Get.toNamed(Routes.TERMINOS_CONDICIONES_DE_USO);
          },
          child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: Text(
                "Política de privacidad",
                style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
              )),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);

}
I leave you here the code of the section where in theory I have placed the textfields.
This works perfectly on an emulator but on a real physical device, it does not perform the correct action. The same thing happens if I change the version of flutter, but I need to keep it at 3.3.3 for other reasons
